# Filter some rows after grouping by user-item pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm given a DataFrame, as shown in the image below:
[image: DataFrame example]

For each user-item pair, I should collect all the events, but the events that happened 1 hour after the maximal timestamp for this particular user-item pair should be removed.

One way I thought of was to extract the user-item pair events, sort them by timestamp, then remove the unnecessary events, and append to some final DataFrame (used for collection). Is there a faster way this could be done?

Comment: can you share the code showing what you have done so far?

Comment: Please add a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) that illustrates your problem, including the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the rows based on duration:

`df.drop(df[df.['duration']> 60].index, inplace=True)`